# Delete system folder not working

Tags: vba, excel, delete-directory

I am using the following code to copy a file, and paste it to a new directory. Then I am trying to delete the old folder and all files within it like so:

```
Source = "\\MI-FILESERVE1\Shared Folders\Shared_Business_Dev\Tasks\" & Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value& "\" & Range("AB" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\log.txt"
Destination = "\\MI-FILESERVE1\Shared Folders\Shared_Business_Dev\Tasks\" & Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("O" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("AB" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\log.txt"
On Error Resume Next
SetAttr Source, vbNormal

FileCopy Source, Destination

On Error Resume Next

dir_name = "\\MI-FILESERVE1\Shared Folders\Shared_Business_Dev\Tasks\" & Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" &  Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\" & Range("AB" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "\"

Dim fso11
Set fso11 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso11.DeleteFolder dir_name

SetAttr Destination, vbHidden
```

No matter what I do the folder will not delete, only the file is getting deleted inside the folder. Please can someone show me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove `On Error Resume Next` and tell us if you are getting any error deleting the folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you want to delete everything, use the `Kill()` method instead to remove all files, then the `RmDir()` method to remove the empty folder.

```
On Error Resume Next
Kill dir_name & "*.*"
RmDir dir_name
Err.Clear            '// Clear error if exists
On Error GoTo 0      '// Reset error handling
```